# Is it possible to build and test a multi target c# dotnet project in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, frameworks, multitargeting

I've a multi target C# dotnet project with these frameworks defined in the csproj file:

```
<TargetFrameworks>net451;net452;net46;net461;netstandard1.3;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

However when browsing the source code, I get lot of errors like:
[image]

Which is strange because I use the correct preprocessor defines like:

```
#if NET452
using Microsoft.Owin;
#else
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
#endif
```

Is this even possible in Visual Studio Code ?

### Edit...

Using Visual Studio 2019, the project builds fine and I can use this framework dropdown like this:
[image]

Comment: what you did here is only the using statement. you need to do special processing for the dll reference (import) as well (never done it. would assume its going to be a pain in the ass too). and who is setting that NET452 macro?

Comment: The full project can be found here: https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net/tree/master/test/WireMock.Net.Tests Maybe that helps understanding what I try to do.